# List all object methods of MyTypes::Object class created by wsdl2perl

Tags: perl, soap, wsdl, bronto

After successfully building my interface with wsdl2perl, I'm looking to retrieve data of this web service but in a generic way.

I'm a newbie with SOAP and WSDL, I plowed thru google/CPAN and of course right here on the Stack, how to get data out via the Web Service API and I prefer Perl! After considering the following options:

1. SOAP::Lite
2. SOAP::WSDL (and yes! My Web Service provide does have a clean wsdl)
3. [wsdl2perl](http://search.cpan.org/~mkutter/SOAP-WSDL-2.00.10/bin/wsdl2perl.pl)!
4. stubmaker

I opted for option 3, (Was that correct choice ?)

I'm looking to get ALL the data returned by the Web Service which returns an array where not all individual attributes of the original class would always be present (pending if it was in the returned XML). I could use [as_hash_ref](http://search.cpan.org/~mkutter/SOAP-WSDL-2.00.10/lib/SOAP/WSDL/Manual/XSD.pod#as_hash_ref)! as follows:

```
my $h = $objects->get_return()->[0]->as_hash_ref();
print join ", " => keys %$h, "\n";
```

That gives me all the keys of the very first of the array, however, I assume, I'm not guaranteed that it would return all possible keys based on what was created by wsdl2perl in the `MyTypes::Object`.

I basically, am looking to get all the class methods of a class whose super class is of type: `SOAP::WSDL::XSD::Typelib::ComplexType` !

I tried to look for some hints in the class itself:

```
confess "Can't locate object method \"$_\" via package \"$class\". \n"
        . "Valid methods are: "
        . join(', ', map { ("get_$_" , "set_$_") } keys %{ $ATTRIBUTES_OF{ $class } })
        . "\n"
```

However digging further, I realize that `$ATTRIBUTES_OF` is filled by the call to `__PACKAGE__->_factory` and I'm stuck how to get all the getters of a given `MyTypes::Object` class created by wsdl2perl.

Simply put, I'm looking to generically iterate over all elements of the array returned by a Web Service, and print out (to csv file) all possible attributes of the `MyTypes::Object` class created by wsdl2perl.